# Architecting ASP.Net MVC 3 with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, entity-framework-4.1, poco

I'm trying to architect my MVC web project and I'm running into a bit of a problem.

I am using EF4.1.  I've created a DataAccess project with the EDMX file.  Then I use the dbContext generator to make my POCO .tt classes.

As it is right now, my Business logic layer can access the POCO classes just fine, but the presentation layer cannot.

I think that I'm supposed to create another level of abstraction and put the dbContext .tt files into their own project so that both the BusinessLogic layer and the Presentation layer can access the POCO classes, but only the BusinessLogic has access to the entity framework. The presentation layer shouldn't need to know anything about EF.

Something like this...

```
POCO Classes - DataAccess
    |             |
    |---------Business Logic
    |             |
    |_________Presentation
```

Am I on the right track here, and if so, do I simply cut/paste the .tt files into the new project or is there a way to force the dbContext add-on to create these in my other project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your presentation layer doesn't have to know anything about the EF. Just reference that project from your presentation layer to access the models.

However - your presentation layer shouldn't ideally be using any of those POCO models. They should be using ViewModels. I dont necessarily believe in the DTOs here as DTOs have a specific purpose. Your repository/data access can return models but generally those get returned to a service layer. The service layer then would return your ViewModel representation to your controller.

This sets you up nicely for dependency injection as well, since into your controller you just inject your service layer. Into your service you can inject then any repositories you need, and so on.

Ironically I think I may be working on a book for this exact subject shortly : )

Comment: So I've been researching ViewModels and I think I understand the concept.  My next question: Do I reference the POCO classes in my model when creating the ViewModel?  Most of the examples I've seen seem to access a repository of some kind, usually called something like _accountRepository.  But I'm not sure where those repositories are stored in the structure.

Comment: my repositories I'll keep in a dataaccess project. The repository will return your EF poco object (or any poco object for that matter). In a separate project I'll have my logic ie services. Some people choose to have extension methods on their model classes that will convert to a viewmodel. I do this in my service layer, for example GetCustomerEditViewModel(int customerId) which gets my entity and in turn maps it to a poco.See Jimmy Bogards article here: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/   I love the automap attribute implementation to ato-convert to a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sending [Data Transfer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx) between your Business Logic and Presentation layers.  This would allow you to shape the data for your views and and prevent information from leaking into the Presentation layer (e.g. if you have a field in your POCO that is needed for your business logic but doesn't need to be available in your Presentation layer).

> The question is, how would you move data to and from the
>   presentation layer? Put another way, should the presentation layer
>   hold a reference to the domain model assembly? (In an Entity Framework
>   scenario, the domain model assembly is just the DLL created out of the
>   EDMX file.)
>
> From a pure design perspective, DTOs are a solution really close to
>   perfection. DTOs help to further decouple presentation from the
>   service layer and the domain model. When DTOs are used, the
>   presentation layer and the service layer share data contracts rather
>   than classes.
>
> A layer of DTOs isolates the domain model from the presentation,
>   resulting in both loose coupling and optimized data transfer.

If you go this route, also check out [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to help with mapping your DTOs to POCOs and vice-versa.

Comment: I think his point is that he wants to use the POCO's as DTO's.  If you don't markup the poco's and use fluent mapping for requirements, then that is quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several ways to structure your project.  What you are referring to is one way, in which you share poco's between all layers.

Another way is to have your POCO's be in the data and business layer, then create a similar object model that's shared between UI and business layer.  Finally, you might also create a third model for the UI only called teh ViewModel.

It all really depends on your needs.  If your object model is very complex, then you might need to simplify it with ViewModels.